# Downloading Files from Google Cloud Storage to Remote Server

Tags: python, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Requirement :

I need  to  execute  a  script  from  a  remote  server  which  download  a  particular  file  from  google  cloud  storage.

Script  should  use  a  service account  where  key  should  be  in  hashicorp  vault.
i  have  already a  hashicorp  vault  setup  established
but  not  sure  how  to  invoke  it  from  shell/python  script

so  if  some  can  help  me  in  how  to  download file  from  GCS  by  using  service account  key in  hashicorp  vault

either  python/shell  script  would  be  fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow the google documentation to download an objects using:

- Console
- gsutil
- Programming Language Script
- curl + rest api

for more information visit this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object)

For a python utility you can use this code

```py
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```